# How can I make a VS file load?

Tags: visual-studio

I've got my project stored in OneDrive and it won't load. This is the view in the Solution Explorer window [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8TQB.png)

Would you know how I could make the project load?

This is in Visual Studio 2017

The location of .csproj file is: C:\Users\t0074311\OneDrive - Cardinal Newman College\Computer Science\Programming\C#\Project\2D Racers\2D Racers 4th\2D Racer\2D Racer

The .sln file as text is here:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.28307.1231
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "2D Racer", "2D Racer\2D Racer.csproj", "{21207F1F-9C62-4D00-B88D-867966A83DC9}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {21207F1F-9C62-4D00-B88D-867966A83DC9}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {21207F1F-9C62-4D00-B88D-867966A83DC9}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {21207F1F-9C62-4D00-B88D-867966A83DC9}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {21207F1F-9C62-4D00-B88D-867966A83DC9}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {D24C8B71-907D-4AB3-B5CE-492F9F46F880}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Can you show the content of the .sln (opened as text file) and the location of the csproj or vbproj?

Comment: Edited the question to show the csproj location and the .sln file as text

Comment: Right-click the project > Reload.  If you got a warning about an untrusted project location and forgot to tell us about it then Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General, "Warn user when the project location is not trusted".   You also didn't tell us how the project got there, you may need to navigate to it with Explorer, right-click the files and tick Unblock.

Comment: I think it was an error with one drive because it now just works

Comment: Looks like your sln file got corrupted for some reason. Can you try opening the `.csproj` files and see if they are opened successfully or not? If yes, you can create a new .sln without losing your original code.